# Elusive groups and vertex-transitive graphs

Tags: gr.group-theory, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

This question is pertaining to finite connected vertex-transitive graphs.

I recently read *"Transitive permutation groups without semiregular subgroup*" by Cameron, Giudici, Jones, Kantor, Klin, Marušič, Nowitz ([publisher link](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/S0024610702003484); [MSN review](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1920405)), where I found the concept of "*elusive groups*".

A permutation  group $G$ acting on a set $X$ is called *elusive* if $G$ is transitive and contains no nontrivial semiregular subgroup (equivalently, no fixed-point-free element of prime order). 
I understand that transitive subgroups of elusive groups are elusive.

My question is: In light of the Polycirculant Conjecture, are the following statements is true?

> Elusive groups cannot be the *full* automorphism group of any vertex-transitive graph.

or

> Elusive groups cannot be any transitive subgroup of the *full* automorphism group of any vertex-transitive graph.

P.S. I am trying to understand how an elusive Group is a hindrance towards the Polycirculant Conjecture.

(Previously [posted on MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3291579/elusive-groups-and-vertex-transitive-graphs).)

Comment: I have edited it, now.

Comment: If $G$ is transitive and elusive, it can just be viewed as transitive subgroup of the automorphism group of the complete graph (on the given set). So if I understand correctly, the second question has a negative answer.

Comment: Please wait more than a few hours before crossposting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any elusive group of degree $n$ is a subgroup of the full automorphism group of the complete graph $K_n$, so your second statement is not true.

The Polycirculant Conjecture asserts that the full automorphism group of a digraph contains a derangement of prime order, i.e, is not elusive.

But while there are various families of elusive groups known, none of these groups are the full automorphism group of a digraph.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. But does that mean we can not have a GRR on an Elusive group, say $M_{11}$?

Comment: No, it does not, I've already explained this to you (in a private communication).
You are conflating abstract groups and permutation groups.
Saying "$M_{11}$ is elusive" without specifying an action is meaningless.
$M_{11}$ is only elusive in one particular action of degree $12$. All its other actions are non-elusive, including its regular one.